# Black screen when booting on an Acer Aspire 5732Z

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

Since I´m getting more and more into linux I got the idea that I should start dualbooting on the family laptop.

First I downloaded wubi to dualboot Ubuntu with Windows 7 home premium on an Acer Aspire 5732Z laptop.

Then I restarted and looked forward for Ubuntu but the screen is almost black.
I can barely see some ad about "excellent apps" but not enough to be able to do anything about it.

Beside being a newbie and computerlexic, what´s my issue?

- Integrated 3D graphics, featuring Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500M (Intel® GMA 4500M with up to 1759 MB of Intel® Dynamic Video Memory Technology 5.0 (64 MB of dedicated video memory, up to 1695 MB of shared system memory), supporting Microsoft® DirectX® 10

Comment: Using Wubi isn't exactly dualbooting. Wubi is just ran as an actual Windows program as far as I know.

Comment: It sounds like you have backlighting issues. Most of the answers seem to focus on 'wubi', however this is an unrelated problem. Please post your full machine specs including graphics card(s).

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is not dualbooting, it is just a way to run Ubuntu from a windows environment.

Dualbooting will require you to shrink a partition on your family PC (unless it already have an unused partition with enough space), and install Ubuntu as well as a bootloader (which is installed automatically, unless you disable it).

The default bootloader that comes with Ubuntu will also allow you to boot into windows, and hence this is the preferred way to have a PC with more than one OS.

I'm sure there's plenty of good software programs that can help you shrink your windows partition, however the easy way to get started with "the real" ubuntu experience is probably simply to burn the ubuntu image to a disk, and boot from that disc.

Simple step-by-step can be found on the ubuntu [download site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

Comment: Wubi - the installer - runs in Windows. But Ubuntu does not. It is a dual boot using a virtual disk.

Answer (score -1):

wubi just fake that it is dual booting, while it actually runs as a program from inside windows, therefore it loads a program in windows memory(whatever is left after windows7) is therefore slow. I would advise you to install it on a separate partition.

Also, there exists a script, which will export your wubi installation to separate partition.

Here is a step by step guide with screenshots for how to move your wubi installation to separate partition

http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-migrate-in-pictures.html

You can download the migration script from [here](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move).

Comment: Wubi - the installer - runs in Windows. But Ubuntu does not. It is a dual boot using a virtual disk.